# Is package.json in angular2 needed in any way to start the application?

Tags: angularjs, json, webpack-2

As I've read in numerous sources, *package.json* does not affect the start up of the angular2 application or any other applications (React.js app for example).Basically, *package.json* just provides information (also called as metadata which help developers to know what they have in their application, some kind of summary for the entire application nodules?

Is this correct what I've written?

I've tried to erase some lines and run the application without the entire *package.json* and the app starts successfully.

In react we had the *webpack.config.js* but I'm aware that in angular this is hidden and is not meant to be modified. However I feel more comfortable when seeing a file which is connected to the **app build procedure** rather than the background scene doing it for me (like in angular).

Can someone please elaborate and confirm if the above thesis are all correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*package.json* file is required.
It contain all the dependency(Dependency, DevDependency and peerDependency) 
with version for the angular project.

When you run npm install command then it will install all the node_modules listed under package.json. So you need to transfer code from one PC to other PC then no need to transfer all node_modules you just need proper package.json file and run npm install command.

Once you install all the dependency in your PC then application will start if you do any changes in this file.

Comment: So basically I require it in the pre-run, but when I actually run my application, ng serve I don't need it anymore?

Comment: That was very helpful tnx

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on the setup.

- The [package.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json) is used in combination with the [npm package manager](https://www.npmjs.com/). It is used to list all dependencies of a project and also allows to run (simple) [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).
- [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) is a module bundler.
- React and Angular are JavaScript frameworks.

Neither Angular nor React require you to use a package.json or Webpack.

> As I've read in numerous sources, package.json does not affect the start up of the angular2 application or any other applications (React.js app for example).

It depends. If you use npm scripts or your build process requires the package.json file, then it is required. Otherwise it is optional. Note, however, that using it is a best-practice in frontend and Node.js projects.

> Basically, package.json just provides information (also called as metadata which help developers to know what they have in their application, some kind of summary for the entire application nodules?

This is correct. The package.json file is also used when you want to publish your project to the npm package repository.

> In react we had the webpack.config.js but I'm aware that in angular this is hidden and is not meant to be modified.

When you mention that the build process is "hidden" in Angular, I guess you are referring to the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/). You are correct, that [Angular CLI uses Webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json) behind the scenes. However, using the Angular CLI in an Angular project is completely optional and you can create your own build configuration.

Comment: So basically you are saying that if I use npm start instead of ng serve, I will need the package json? In other words npm start will use package json to point to the nodule folders and files?

Comment: @masterach More or less. `npm start` will run a script that is configured in the package.json file. But this does not imply that you actually have a node_modules directory. Running scripts and dependency management are two features of npm, but you can use one without the other.

Comment: Of-course, but it will still (npm start) go to see what is written in package json and therefore follow the package json commands, it will at least try and run, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

package.json initially is used to define a nodejs package, which can be then submitted to the npm and be installed by other people.
It describe the basic info like name, version and dependency. Now you understand, your "project" is actually a package in a way, which needs dependency of course.
It's like the requirement.txt in django project, can be used to store the dependency of this project, and to quickly build up the dev environment in case you change machine.